# Field contraint on iOS Keyboard

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way on iOS to get something better than the normal keyboard when the field is constrained to numeric.

[keyboard I get on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a4RG.jpg)

Instead, I would like to get something closer from Android. Like just the number instead of all the junk around i get here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
myTextField.setConstraint(TextArea.NUMERIC);
```

There are many constraints e.g. `PASSWORD`, `DECIMAL`, `EMAIL` etc...

Comment: I did try this but it put the keyboard I screenshoted.

Comment: That's a numeric keyboard on iOS, you might want to use PHONENUMBER constraint which I'm assuming is what you really want...